# Help with hover jquery

Tags: jquery

The below code hides `.titlerow` on hover of `.row`.  How do I change the code so if the mouse isn't hovered on any row then the first `.titlerow` is hidden?

```
echo "<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>";

$(function() {

    $('.row').hover(function() {

    $(this).find('.titlerow').hide();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.titlerow').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this is what you mean, if not please elaborate on what your intensions are...

html:

```
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
<div class='row'><div class='titlerow'></div></div>
```

script:

```
$(function() {
    $('.row').hover(function() {
        $('.titlerow').first().show();
        $(this).find('.titlerow').hide();

    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.titlerow').show();
      $('.titlerow').first().hide();
    });

    // hide the first titlerow
    $('.titlerow').first().hide();
});
```

**edit**

in the code above i made some fixes for your new request. + a working example can be found below

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/muqxj/

Comment: thanks it works initially but when i hover over a row and then leave all together the first titlerow is shown.

Comment: well then please explain in more detail what you expect to happen, because i don't quite understand what the expected behavior is... if you hover you want it to hide on leave you want it to show, but when does the first one needs to be hidden?

Comment: i want the first .titlerow to be hidden initially, which is correct. On hover of .row, .titlerow is hidden, which is correct.  Now if all .row is not hovered, then the first .titlerow should be hidden again, which it isn't.